# Python "requests" with decorator

Tags: python, python-requests, decorator, python-decorators

There is my code I'm trying to do:

```
import json
import requests

class Request(object):
  def __init__(self, method, path):
    self.method = method
    ## Q1
    self.url = ''.join([***MyClass.host***, path])
    self.h = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    }

  def __call__(self, f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      # Q2
      getattr(requests, self.method)(url = self.url, headers = h***, data = json.dumps(body)***)
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, host):
    self.host = host

  @Request(method = "post", path = "/add_mission")
  def AddMission(self, mission):
    body = {
      "mission_id": mission
    }

  @Request(method = "get", path = "/system_info")
  def GetInfo(self):
    print("I want get info")
```

There are some questions hope someone can solve my problems:
1. How can my decorator "Request" get the variable "host" from "MyClass"? (In comment ## Q1)
2. How can I pass the function's variable "body" to decorator, is it possible? (In comment ## Q2)

Because I need to access different url(host+path) with [post, get, delete].
I'm not sure isn't decorator match on this case?
Or maybe there are better ways to deal with this case?

Comment: You don't need `getattr(requests, self.method)`. `requests.get` is already just a wrapper around `requests.request("GET", ...)`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for reminding. Your reply clear up my confusion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host is available once you call the decorated function, via the invoking object's `host` attribute, so wait until you actually call the method to build the URL. You'll want to *call* the underlying function to get back a value, if any, to use as the payload.

```
import json
import requests

class Request(object):
    def __init__(self, method, path):
        self.method = method.upper()
        self.h = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }
        self.path = path

  def __call__(self, f):
      def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs):
          payload = f(*args, **kwargs)
          args = {
              'method': self.method,
              'url': 'http://{}/{}'.format(obj.host, self.path),
              'headers': self.h
          }
          if payload is not None:
              args['json'] = payload
          return requests.request(**args)
      return wrapper


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host

    @Request(method="post", path="/add_mission")
    def AddMission(self, mission):
        return {"mission_id": mission}

    @Request(method="get", path="/system_info")
    def GetInfo(self):
        print("I want get info")
```

Then you can write, for example,

```
api = MyClass("www.example.com")
add_response = api.AddMission("mars")
info_response = api.GetInfo()
```

Each decorated function returns the `Response` object produced by the call to `requests.request`.

You might consider subclasses of `Request` for each method:

```
class GetRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__("GET", path)

class PostRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__("POST", path)

# etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I changed `payload = f()` to `payload = f(obj, *args, **kwargs)`, and it works as my expect.
I think I need to learn more about decorator and wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

The code now has all types of requests covered, plus the possibility of having authentication on each request.

[Code on github](https://github.com/tuxcell/Python-requests-with-decorator)

Pros:

1. Easy to read, less code, therefore easier to maintain.
2. Easy to add new methods or to update the existing ones.

Cons:

1. Can't get it to work on pytest.
2. Less "standard" API might cause hard to debug errors.
3. Less "standard" API might need changes to the wrapper that can be tricky.
4. Big performance loss because of all the nested function calls (methods/decorators are functions)

```
import ujson
import requests

class Request(object):
    def __init__(self, method, path, h={ "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" }):
        self.path = path
        #print(f"PATH {path}")
        self.method = method.upper()
        self.h = h

    def __call__(self, f):
        def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs):
            payload = f(obj, *args, **kwargs)
            #print(f"PAYLOAD {payload}")
            if (payload is not None) and (self.method == "GET" or self.method == "DELETE"):
                dic_key = list(payload.keys())[0]
                self.path = "{}/?{}={}".format(self.path, dic_key, payload[dic_key])
                payload = None
            args = {
                'method': self.method,
                'url': 'http://{}/{}'.format(obj.host, self.path),
                'headers': self.h
            }
            if payload is not None:
                args['json'] = payload
            return requests.request(**args)
        return wrapper

class GetRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, path, h=None):
        if h is None:
            super().__init__("GET", path)
        else:
            super().__init__("GET", path, h)

class PostRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, path, h=None):
        if h is None:
            super().__init__("POST", path)
        else:
            super().__init__("POST", path, h)

class PutRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, path, h=None):
        if h is None:
            super().__init__("PUT", path)
        else:
            super().__init__("PUT", path, h)

class DeleteRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, path, h=None):
        if h is None:
            super().__init__("DELETE", path)
        else:
            super().__init__("DELETE", path, h)

myToken = 'Secret_key_1234567890'

class DecoRequests(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host

    @GetRequest(path="userlist", h={'access_token':myToken})
    def list_employees(self):
        pass

    @GetRequest(path="users", h={'access_token':myToken})
    def list_employee(self, username):
        return {"username":username}

    @PostRequest(path="users", h={'access_token':myToken})
    def add_employee(self, employee_data):
        return employee_data

    @PutRequest(path="users", h={'access_token':myToken})
    def update_employee(self, employee_data):
        return employee_data

    @DeleteRequest(path="users", h={'access_token':myToken})
    def rm_employee(self, username):
        return {"username":username}
```